# Non-string key in NSDictionary object?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

I've parsed some JSON data using NSJSONSerialization from the Foundation framework - however, I'm getting a weird key for an NSDictionary group as follows

```
"stop_times" =     (
            {
        "departure_time" = "5:48a";
        "departure_timestamp" = 1355309284;
        "service_id" = 1;
        shape = "Scarborough RT To Kennedy Station";
            }
```

Any idea what the key "shape" might be? Is it a string? I didn't think so since it wasn't surrounded with double quotation marks. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `description` method of `NSDictionary` (which is used if you output a dictionary with NSLog, or print it in the debugger) encloses strings in quotation marks only if they contain special characters.

This output format is described in [Old-Style ASCII Property Lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html) in the "Property List Programming Guide":

> The quotation marks can be omitted if the string is composed strictly
>   of alphanumeric characters and contains no white space (numbers are
>   handled as strings in property lists). ...

Note that in general you cannot deduce the type from the NSLog() output. `123` can be a number or a string. But in this case, `shape` can only be a string.

Answer (score -2):

this is not a valid JSON string.

u can check the same putting this string in any json viewer e.g. http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: ask your server guy to provide you with the valid json response

Comment: It is the `NSDictionary`, not the JSON data, that is shown in the question.