# Swift json some keys with quotes some without

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I use get json data from remote and use JSON(data) in swift with SwiftyJson, now problem is when i do:

```
println(jsonObj.object)
```

i get this:

```
{
    id = 3642;
    name = "Test";
    "front_image" = "/image/dasad.jpg";
    "is_new" = 0;
    price = "100";
}
```

I have problem here, becouse some keys in this object are with double quotes, some without, so i can't get value with `jsonObj.objectForKey("front_image")!.string`

When i see json url from browser, this is what i get:

```
{
    "id" = 3642;
    "name" = "Test";
    "front_image" = "/image/dasad.jpg";
    "is_new" = 0;
    "price" = "100";
}
```

is this SwiftyJson bug, or?
What is solution for this?

Comment: What error are you getting with `objectForKey()` ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "I can't get value"? Does the compiler complain? Does your program crash? What happens?

Comment: `sharedAd.ad.objectForKey("front_image")!.string` gives me `nil`, but it isn't nil.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836553/non-string-key-in-nsdictionary-object: The *description* of NSDictionary encloses a string in quotation marks if it contains any non-alphanumeric character. This quotation marks appear only in the println() output and are not part of the key itself. So your actual problem must be something different...

Answer (score 0):

The keys are ALWAYS strings, but the quotes show up in the console when special characters that would require an escape (e.g. the underscore "_") are used.

As stated by [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r):

Compare stackoverflow.com/questions/13836553/…: The description of NSDictionary encloses a string in quotation marks if it contains any non-alphanumeric character. This quotation marks appear only in the println() output and are not part of the key itself. So your actual problem must be something different...

Answer (score -3):

The quotes means the value is a string and not a integer. It isn't a bug or something.

Comment: Though so too, but it appears the real problem are the keys. Look carefully ;)