# NSArray can't get value of key with quotes around it

Tags: ios, swift

I have this method which chokes on fetching the `team_id`. I think it has something to do with the key containing quotes around it as you can see in the println content below.

How can I get the `team_id` from this object? It prints out as `team_id = Optional(268)` even if I try `println("team_id = \(team_id!)")`

FYI UpcomingEvents is an NSArray.

```
func loadUpcomingEvents() -> Void {
        var event = Event()

        event.getUpcoming() {
            (upcomingEvents, error) -> Void in

            for currentEvent in upcomingEvents! {
                println("FULL EVENT = \(currentEvent)")
                let name = currentEvent["name"] as NSString
                println("name = \(name)")

                let team_id = currentEvent["team_id"]
                println("team_id = \(team_id)")
            }
        }
    }
```

FULL EVENT prints this out:

```
FULL EVENT = {
    name = "Lunch Broomball";
    "team_id" = 29;  <-- team_id has quotes around it. why/how to fetch the value?
}
```

** EDIT **

It seems the only way I can get it to print without the "Optional" is to use an exclamation on both lines like this:

```
let team_id = currentEvent["team_id"]!
println("team_id = \(team_id!)")
```

But why is that? Seems to be only for `team_id`

Also why does this code fail?

```
let name = currentEvent["name"] as NSString
println("name = \(name)")

let team_id = currentEvent["team_id"] as NSString //<-- FAILS HERE with error message below
println("team_id = \(team_id)")
```

Error:

```
...
0x1050c89b3:  leaq   0xc158(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x1050c89ba:  movq   %rax, 0x87427(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x1050c89c1:  int3   
0x1050c89c2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Comment: What does `currentEvent["team_id"]` print?

Comment: First thing's first. Upgrade to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0(+) if at all possible!

Comment: `currentEvent["\"team_id\""]` !? and remove the double `!!`!

Comment: currentEvent is an NSDictionary, not an NSArray. And the key does not have quotes around it, that is only how the description method of NSDictionary prints keys with special characters, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/13837313/1187415.

Comment: Arrays aren't accessed by key, but by index. I think it is a safe assumption that your currentEvent objects are dictionaries stored in an array.

Comment: `currentEvent["team_id"]` should just work – but why do you unwrap it *twice* ??

Comment: I updated my question. I can't get it to print without "Optional..". I tried the double unwrap b/c I read something on the internet but that didn't work.

Comment: If `currentEvent["team_id"] as NSString` fails then the value is not an NSString. Perhaps it is an NSNumber ?  – In any case, the problem has nothing to do with "keys with quotes around it"!

Comment: By changing it to `currentEvent["team_id"] as NSNumber` instead of `currentEvent["team_id"] as NSString` it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `currentEvent` is a native swift dictionary (not an NSDictionary).

When fetching an object from a dictionary with `currentEvent["team_id"]` it will return an optional (because the value might not be in the dictionary). You will have to unwrap the value for it to be usable. In your case you probably put another optional within the dictionary which is why it makes you unwrap it twice.

Also it is a good practise to unwrap a value in for example an if statement like so:

```
if let team_id = currentEvent["team_id"] as? NSNumber
{
     print("Team-id", team_id)
}
```

It will try to unwrap the value to a NSNumber, if it does not succeed it wont print out the team_id. Some more information about optionals:

> The concept of optionals doesn’t exist in C or Objective-C. The
>   nearest thing in Objective-C is the ability to return nil from a
>   method that would otherwise return an object, with nil meaning “the
>   absence of a valid object.” However, this only works for objects—it
>   doesn’t work for structures, basic C types, or enumeration values. For
>   these types, Objective-C methods typically return a special value
>   (such as NSNotFound) to indicate the absence of a value. This approach
>   assumes that the method’s caller knows there is a special value to
>   test against and remembers to check for it. Swift’s optionals let you
>   indicate the absence of a value for any type at all, without the need
>   for special constants.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html